# Henselization of a smooth affine scheme in closed smooth subscheme and henselization of normal bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Hi!

Let $Z\hookrightarrow X$ - is a closed embedding of smooth affine schemes. Let $N_{X/Z}$ be corresponding normal bundle.
I am curious if there is an isomorphism between henselizations:
$X^h_Z\cong (N_{X/Z})^h_Z$ ?

Here by henselization here I mean a scheme $U\stackrel{etale}\rightarrow X$ with an embedding $Z\hookrightarrow U,$ which has the universal property: for any other such scheme $U'$ there is a map $U'\rightarrow U,$ that respects the embedding of $Z.$

It is also interesting if the weaker statement is true:
Is there an isomorphism between the completions of $X$ in $Z$ and normal bundle in $Z:$

$\widehat{X_Z}\cong \widehat{N_{X/Z}}$

Thank you!